# Things to back up when moving from ubuntu to fedora

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, backup

I have decided to move from ubuntu to fedora for a change, but I don't know what files and directories to back up other than `/home`, and if i should back up the dot files and directories in `/home` or not? Any help will be appreciated :)